# Replacing a NSMutableString with another string

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablestring

I want to replace NSMutableString with another String (Not a part of string but complete string)

I tried different approaches but couldnt find a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSMutableString stringWithString:xxxx]; is the solution. That was simple!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something called `setString`. This will over-write the previous string with whatever new string you want.

Try -

```
[yourMutableString setString:@"new string"];
```

Check [NSMutableString doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There are other methods like `appendString` etc.

Comment: [NSMutableString stringWithString:xxxx]; is the solution. That was simple!